# Partial View not showing data

Tags: view, partial

I have a partial view which does not show the data. Here is a simple version. Here are my Models. The parent and child records

```
namespace Partial.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Parent
     {
         [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage   ("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Parent()
        {
            this.Children = new HashSet<Child>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Partial.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Child
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> ParentID { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual Parent Parent { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here are my controllers which only involve the index and edit forms.

```
namespace Partial.Controllers
{
    public class ParentsController : Controller
    {
        private PartialEntities db = new PartialEntities();

        // GET: Parents
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Parents.ToList());
        }

namespace Partial.Controllers
{
    public class ChildrenController : Controller
{
    private PartialEntities db = new PartialEntities();

    // GET: Children
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var children = db.Children.Include(c => c.Parent);
        return View(children.ToList());

    }
```

Here is my view. Parent Form which is the edit form. Which should display the children index form

```
@model Partial.Models.Parent

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Parent</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        Html.Partial("~/Views/Children/Index.cshtml", new List<Partial.Models.Child> ());
    </td>        
</tr>
</table>

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Child Form which should display the children but doesn't

```
@model IEnumerable<Partial.Models.Child>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parent.Description)
    </th>
    <th></th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Parent.Description)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: More context to this question would be helpful figuring out exactly where this went wrong.

Comment: What more would you like to see?

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try Code
```

Remove the code

```
 Html.Partial("~/Views/Children/Index.cshtml", new List<Partial.Models.Child> ());
```

replace Code

@{Html.RenderAction("Index","Children");}

```
Sysntext For :


 @Html.RenderAction("Action name","Controller name",Route values)
```